# Inconsistent SpectralEmbedding results from python

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I am trying to translate some code from `python` into `scala`. I am specifically looking to generate the same results as generated by `SpectralEmbedding`. At the moment I am investigating the [LaplacianEigenmap](https://haifengl.github.io/smile/api/java/smile/manifold/LaplacianEigenmap.html) from https://haifengl.github.io/smile/

The problem I have is I am unable to get a consistent result from python! Running the following code gives different results depending on the OS.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.manifold import SpectralEmbedding

data=np.array([
    ['',1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,'timewindow'],
    ['acai',5,4,13,8,6,2,6,8,2,6,1,9,7,8,6,9,8,5,5,11,1,7,3,8,1],
    ['acerola',3,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1],
    ['adzuki beans',0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
    ['agar',2,0,1,2,0,0,1,3,2,1,4,2,0,1,2,4,5,8,7,2,4,3,5,24,1],
    ['agave',5,2,7,6,4,1,9,4,4,4,6,5,10,7,4,8,10,7,2,11,8,9,8,6,1],
    ['ajwain',0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
    ['alfalfa',1,1,2,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,2,4,3,3,1,0,0,2,2,1,0,1,2,0,1],
    ['algae',0,1,0,3,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,2,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1],
    ['allspice',0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,1,1],
    ['almond',194,140,329,276,207,268,310,331,363,332,378,421,503,487,499,559,581,553,602,637,573,577,641,554,1],
    ['aloe vera',0,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,3,2,2,2,1,5,2,1,1,1,4,1,0,1],
    ['amaranth',2,0,2,0,0,1,1,2,0,0,0,2,0,3,1,2,1,0,2,2,3,1,3,0,1],
    ['amari',0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,2,1,1,0,5,1,0,3,1,0,0,1,1,1,1],
    ['angostura',0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1],
    ['angustifolia',0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1],
    ['anise',2,0,6,3,0,1,3,2,0,0,4,6,2,3,2,6,2,4,1,2,2,0,3,6,1],
    ['apple cider vinegar',0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,2,0,0,1,0,0,0,1],
    ['apple',157,108,212,203,127,170,232,256,334,419,431,327,376,366,415,407,355,327,359,404,555,694,580,402,1],
    ['apricot',9,3,8,14,2,12,22,10,8,12,8,15,15,11,12,17,12,14,26,19,9,23,13,20,1],
    ['arjuna',0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1]
])


columns = 24
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data[1:,1:],
                  index=data[1:,0],
                  columns=data[0,1:])

model = SpectralEmbedding(n_components=2, random_state=13,eigen_solver="arpack")
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)
LE_model = model.fit_transform(df.ix[:,0:columns])

df_reduced = pd.DataFrame(LE_model)
print(df_reduced)
```

When I run using python2 or python3 in a Jupiter notebook running on Docker (Linux) I get:

```
           0         1
0   0.016043 -0.050914
1   0.048082  0.016466
2   0.192327  0.065864
3   0.210040 -0.043099
4   0.024065 -0.076371
5   0.192327  0.065864
6   0.840161 -0.172394
7   0.096164  0.032932
8   0.048082  0.016466
9   0.110486  0.687106
10  0.210040 -0.043099
11  0.420081 -0.086197
12  0.048082  0.016466
13  0.048082  0.016466
14  0.096164  0.032932
15  0.420081 -0.086197
16  0.096164  0.032932
17  0.110486  0.687106
18  0.008022 -0.025457
19  0.096164  0.032932
```

When I run using python3 from Intellij on Windows:

```
           0         1
0   0.369416 -0.031546
1  -0.023761 -0.030871
2  -0.095044 -0.123483
3   0.100685  0.176579
4   0.554124 -0.047319
5  -0.095044 -0.123483
6   0.402739  0.706316
7  -0.047522 -0.061742
8  -0.023761 -0.030871
9   0.427355 -0.409445
10  0.100685  0.176579
11  0.201370  0.353158
12 -0.023761 -0.030871
13 -0.023761 -0.030871
14 -0.047522 -0.061742
15  0.201370  0.353158
16 -0.047522 -0.061742
17  0.427355 -0.409445
18  0.184708 -0.015773
19 -0.047522 -0.061742
```

If I can't get a consistent result from python I will be unable to ensure my scala code is working as expected.

Is there a reason for the difference?
Are there any JVM based version of `SpectralEmbedding` that are consistent with the python version?

Comment: I get different results each time I run your code on the same system. Can you confirm that? (There is also a warning *Graph is not fully connected, spectral embedding **may not work as expected**.*)

Comment: If I make the warning go away by using a different data set (`data = np.arange(20*30).reshape(30, 20)`) the results are consistent. If I then remove the number of rows (`data = np.arange(20*10).reshape(10, 20)`) the warning appears and results are inconsistent again. Conclusion: your data is not suitable for spectral embedding.

Comment: @kazemakase I did see that warning but didn't think it would cause the results to change with every run. I will retry with a different dataset.

Comment: I did not expect it either. Not even after poking around in the source code could I find a reason for it...